# Cannot convert value of type 'string' to expected argument type [Any]

Tags: swift

I got the following error when adding an variable from textfield.text to an NSMutableArray.

Cannot convert value of type 'string' to expected argument type [Any]

```
    let itemsObjects = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")

    var items:NSMutableArray

    if var items = itemsObjects as? NSMutableArray {

    items.addObjects(from: (textField.text!))

    }
```

Shouldn't type Any include type String ?

Thank you,

Comment: `addObjects(from:)` expects an array (`Array<Any>`, a.k.a `[Any]`), whose elements are added to the array its called on. `textField.text!` is a `String`, which doesn't satisfy this requirement. What's the original declaration of `itemObjects`? You shouldn't be using `NSMutableArray` in Swift, in the first place

Comment: Edited with declaration. Why is NSMutableArray bad in swift?

Comment: They're not type safe, andtheir method calls are slow because they go through the Objective C runtime. Use Swift's native data types as much as possible. They bridge easily to/from their ObjC counterparts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift**.

Unlike the immutable types they are not related to the Swift counterparts and cannot be bridged to each other. Further they defeat Swift's strong type system.

`UserDefaults` has a dedicated method to get an array, the `var` keyword makes objects mutable in Swift. `textField.text` is s single object, the appropriate API is `append`

```
if let itemsObjects = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "items") {
    var items = itemsObjects
    items.append(textField.text!)
}
```

Comment: You can just use `if var items = ...`

Comment: @Alexander Yes of course, I just wanted to describe how to make an immutable object mutable.